# How to insert the image field in the menu links

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes

How to insert the image field in the menu links? I've added an image field in the vocabulary I've created and uploaded image on each terms. I am able to display those images and the other fields I require using the [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and I've used the [taxonomy_menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) to add the terms in the menu links, but one of my requirements is to display those image into the menu links. I don't think that the menu_icons module is the solution, I don't want to double up the work in uploading the image. Please bear with my English and hoping that I explained it well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the module [Menu Minipanels](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_minipanels). This module will allow you to use views and custom blocks inside the menu.

Or you can customize the menu display as specified [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/988694).